# Entity Framework 6 Design Architecture For Images

Tags: c#, database-design, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

The point is: I use EF6 and have 2 entities which may have some connected images, but these entities are not connected with any hierarchy (e.g EntityA, EntityB).

These images may exist in different size - so entities are Image, ImageVersion, ImageSize

```
public class Image
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ImageVersion : Image
{
    public ImageSize ImageSize { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}

public enum ImageType { EntityA, EntityB };

public class ImageSize
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ImageType ImageType { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

The question is: how to create navigation property in `Image` to entity which this image belongs to? (`EntityA` and `EntityB` are not in one hierarchy but may have images)?

Comment: You cannot have a *single* navigation property from `Image` that would link to `EntityA` once, and to `EntityB` some other time. You need to have *two* distinct navigation properties - one going to `EntityA`, the other to `EntityB` - and only one of them can be active at any given time

Comment: Yep. The recurring *polymorphic associations* question.

Comment: So, how it would be used if I have 2 navigation properties? Check if one of them is null? Or I may change this design somehow? As possible variant - define some base class ImagedEntity and inherit EntityA and EntityB from ImagedEntity? I think interface IImagedEntity would be better, but EF does not support interfaces in navigation properties as far as I know.